# Recuperar información de un SSD

Tags: linux, cmd, windows10

tengo un disco sólido el cual tiene dos sistemas operativos (windows 10 y linux mint).

El detalle es necesito recuperar la información que tenía dentro de Windows, pero en Windows el boot\bcd está dañado. Dentro de Linux no puedo abrir la partición de Windows, solo la de Reservado por el Sistema.

Para no repetir las respuestas, les comento los pasos que seguí para intentar recuperar la información:

1-. Cargué un USB booteable de Windows e intenté ver las particiones en el menú de instalación, pero me salía el famoso mensaje de que faltan los controladores para el dispositivo. Y no aparecía ninguna partición.
2-. Intenté reparar el boot\bcd desde la consola de comandos desde la opción de Reparar del USB booteable
3-. Reparar la partición con TestDisk (desde otro Windows y Linux)

El detalle que noté es que al conectar en SATA el SSD en una PC que tiene windows, se inicia creo que el `chkdsk` pero desafortunadamente nunca pasa del 10%

Muchas gracias por ayuda.

Comment: Dices que desde Linux no puedes abrir la partición de Windows, asumo que fue porque no apareció en el gestor de archivos ni en el escritorio. ¿Pero seguiste algún procedimiento adicional para intentar acceder a dicha partición?. Si es así, ¿podrías editar la pregunta para incluir detalladamente los pasos que seguiste para intentar acceder a la partición de Windows desde Linux? Por favor, indica las rutas a las que intentaste acceder y, si aplica, los comandos exactos que utilizaste.

Comment: Hola, que tal, gracias por responder, en realidad no he seguido algún paso para recuperar la partición desde linux mas que el utilizar testdisk el cual se queda colgado cuando introduzco el SSD como unidad externa

Answer (score 0):

Para poder montar particiones de windows desde linux necesitas el paquete ntfs-3g. Debes instalarlo si no lo tienes en tu Linux Mint:

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Una vez instalado, busca esa partición:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Recuerda qué partición es la corrupta (tendrá un nombre del tipo dev/sdX, donde X será el número de la partición.

```
sudo ntfsfix dev/partición de windows
```

Con suerte, este último comando reparará tu partición.
No tengo claro que ntfsfix se incluya al instalar ntfs-3g ; si no es así, instala de la manera el paquete ntfsprogs.
Suerte.